# getting logout redirect issues for Azure web apps using Azure AD and adl4j

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, adfs

I'm facing issue when the user tries to logout of my application. I have specified the logout redirect URL. This issue is not consistent. Only few users are facing this issue when they try to logout. Especially in the IE browser v11.
Don't know the root cause for it, whether it is ADFS issue or Azure AD issue.
Please throw some light.
Below is the error message I'm getting

An error occurred. 
Contact your administrator for more information.

Error details

•         Activity ID: 4caf96c8-a3af-4acd-088e-0180000000e6

•         Error time: Fri, 21 Dec 2018 09:05:13 GMT

•         Cookie: enabled

•         User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36

Comment: This is an error returned from AD FS. Without seen a Fiddler trace and/or AD FS event log we cannot comment on the exact cause. You should consider raising a support case with Microsoft to get a better answer based on diagnosing data from your environment.

Comment: AD FS event log is the right place to check root cause for this issue